# read() not reading file's contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-read

Python 3 code:

```
file = open("amdPricesPrices.txt", "a+")
prices = file.read()
print(prices)
```

Text file contents:

```
69.40 69.30 67.61 76.09 78.19 77.67 86.71 84.85
```

When I execute this code it does not print anything but a blank line.

Comment: have you tried change the mode from a+ to r?

Comment: More context on @SirBaum answer: the second parameter, `a+` in this case, is the mode to open the file. Opening a file in `a` opens it for appending. If you just need to read from the file, open it with `r`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: yeah sorry. Thanks for the additional information ^^

Answer (score 1):

Using the mode `"a+"` starts reading from (and writing to) from the end of the file.

You need to either `file.seek(0)` to the start of the while, or use one of the other opening modes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036. If you are just reading from the file, you don't have to specify the mode, it will use the deault of `"r"`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a+ is for appending to a file, while using r is for reading a file.

```
file = open("amdPricesPrices.txt", "r")
prices = file.read()
print(prices)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want read-write access (without truncating the file) and with the file positioned at the start of the file, then open with mode `'r+'` -- although `'a+'` would work if followed by `file.seek(0)`.